# Symfony3 can't find response component

Tags: php, symfony

Just started learning Symfony today and am trying to set up a test page. Following their getting started guide and doing the lucky number tutorial. I've run into an issue with the php file I copied from the tutorial here:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @Route("/api/lucky/number")
     */
    public function apiNumberAction()
    {
        $data = array(
            'lucky_number' => rand(0, 100),
        );

        return new Response(
            json_encode($data),
            200,
            array('Content-Type' => 'application/json')
        );
    }
}
?>
```

I am getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\web\lucky\number.php on line 21`

If anyone could point me in the right direction to fixing this issue or even to a better tutorial for someone getting started, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: you may don't have included the autoloader

Comment: I added `require_once('vendor/autoload.php');` which is where my autoloader is and it finds the file but does not fix the issue.

Comment: since you get the error in `number.php`, let see that page

Comment: that is number.php in the post

Comment: and where did you included the autoloader?

Comment: I edited my original post to show how the page looks now there is currently no autoloader I wasn't sure which one to include

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108723/discussion-between-federico-and-habitat).

Answer (score 0):

The file in the post should be named src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php but you said it is named web\lucky\number.php. If that is true, that must be fixed first.